# Automatically convert migrated questions to bounty-style acceptance?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration, auto-acceptance

When a question is migrated, and the author is nowhere to be found on the new site, how exactly can anybody be awarded for providing the most up-voted answer? (Whether they answered before or after the migration is irrelevant.) Well, besides getting the votes for providing a good answer. Is there currently any method of accepting a "correct answer" for questions that underwent migration?

Would it be reasonable to automatically accept the highest-voted answer 48 hours after migration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of 'Accepting an Answer' is to recognize the fact that no matter how many people respond (and how many people vote) there is only one person who can determine which answer works best for them, and that is the OP.

If the OP disappears, then the an answer cannot be the 'accepted' answer. If the Accepted answer is simply "the one with the most votes", then we already have a way of determining that. We simply check which answer has the most votes.

Adding an "autoaccepted" answer won't help bubble an answer to the top, because the answer is already the top answer by default anyway.

Comment: +1: Good point about the "bubbling".

Answer (score 4):

My knee-jerk reaction is "No". That's the punishment for answering questions you know don't belong. ;)

**EDIT:** The above of course was directed at migrated answers. Anyone answering a question *after* it has been migrated can see for themselves that the author is non-existent, so they already know there will probably be no acceptance.

Comment: Anybody coming across that question in the future will be seeing it in the correct context (residing on the proper site), and should be able to see an accepted answer. Why punish everybody else because the author of the question made a mistake?

Comment: @Jonathan: In such a case, upvotes should suffice in helping the reader determine the "best" answer.